# Partition recognized as unusable during ubuntu installation

Tags: partitioning, boot-partition

I want to dual boot windows 7 with ubuntu but during installing ubuntu shows the partition i created for ubuntu in windows as unusable.Basically i have 3 partition and one system reserved.

Partition C - where all program files are present.

Partition D - where my movies and songs are present

Partition E - where i store office document.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iPfs.png)

And one partition is system reserved which was created when i removed windows 8 and installed windows 7.
So when i create a free space partition for ubuntu it recognize it as unusable.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Cvic.jpg)

- Before this problem
  After installing win7 over win8 i tried to install ubuntu but at that ubuntu was unable to recognize any of my partition instead showing only one single partition.Later on i found out it was some Gpt-MBR problem.
  So i used Fixpart to fix that problem.and it was fixed.

Comment: @Rod Smith  The unallocated space/partition is formed by shirking one of the partition.I can remove the extra space.

Comment: @Rod Smith ...Thnx Rod .....I solved my problem..I deleted one of my partition and extended the another one..Thus i was left with 2 primary partition and one system reserved partition..  and Hola i was successful in installing ubuntu...

Answer (score 1):

First, be aware that you did something very dangerous: You should ***NEVER*** use Windows' own partitioning tool to create partition(s) for Linux. ***NEVER.*** The Windows tools have known bugs that cause all manner of problems, particularly when increasing the number of partitions beyond four on a [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) disk, which you have. Fortunately, you don't seem to have run into these problems. I'm leading with this point because I don't want you, or somebody else who reads this, to make that mistake. It's OK to use the Windows tools to shrink an existing partition, but that's it.

Second, the screen shots to which you've linked do not show five partitions; they show four partitions and unallocated space between two of those partitions. The GUIs are easy to misinterpret. With that in mind, you should also know that MBR supports a maximum of four primary partitions, which is what you've got. That's why GParted identifies the unallocated space as "unusable" -- it literally cannot be carved up into additional partitions, because you've already used your four primary partition slots.

Note the qualifier word *primary.* MBR also supports *logical* partitions, but they must exist within a special type of primary partition known as an *extended* partition. Thus, when you need more than four partitions, the usual solution is to make at most three primary partitions, one extended partition, and as many logical partitions as you need. The trick in your case is that you've already got four primary partitions, so you can't create the extended partition that you need to create your logical partitions. There are ways around this dilemma, but the best way to proceed depends on how you're using those partitions.

I note that GParted seems not to have fully identified `/dev/sda4` -- GParted says that it's NTFS, but says the amount of used space is "unknown." If you created `/dev/sda4` in Windows for Linux's use, one approach is to delete it and create an extended partition in its place. The trouble with this approach is that if you delete `/dev/sda4`, you'll have two areas of unused space, and you can create just one extended partition. Thus, you must either convert `/dev/sda3` into a logical partition or move it to the left so that you'll have one big area of contiguous free space for your extended partition. If `/dev/sda3` is not a boot disk, then converting it to a logical partition should work. (Windows can boot only from primary partitions, so you should *not* convert `/dev/sda3` to logical form if you're booting from it.) Moving the partition may be time-consuming, and imposes a risk of data loss, but may be an acceptable solution if you've got a good backup.

Another solution (which overlaps with the preceding one) is to convert one or more of your existing partitions from primary to logical form. You can do this with my [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) program, which comes in the `gdisk` package in Ubuntu. You should definitely be able to convert `/dev/sda3` from primary to logical form with FixParts, and you *might* be able to convert other partitions, too. ***DO NOT*** convert your Windows boot partition, though. Once you convert partition(s) from primary to logical form, you can use GParted to adjust the size of the extended partition and create new logical partitions for use by Ubuntu. (Unlike Windows, Ubuntu has no problems booting from a logical partition.) Unfortunately, I can't be very specific about what to convert in this scenario, since I don't know enough about what each of your partitions does. I recommend you read the FixParts documentation, identify your existing partitions' functions, and if necessary ask more questions before proceeding. If you go this route, you'll probably end up using at least two partitioning tools (FixParts and GParted), and maybe more (the Windows tool may be slightly safer than GParted if you have to move or resize existing NTFS partitions).

Comment: Also if you used Windows to convert from a Windows 8 install to Windows 7, you also converted from gpt partitioning to MBR(msdos) partitioning. But Windows does not do that correctly and Rod's fixparts is required to remove the backup gpt partition table.

Comment: Windows 7 supports EFI-mode booting from GPT disks, so converting from Windows 8 to Windows 7 would not *necessarily* entail the change that oldfred describes. That said, it's *easier* to boot the Windows installer in BIOS mode than in EFI mode, so such a conversion is certainly a strong possibility. That said, the fact that GParted showed the partitions suggests there's no problem.